# Does touching the urine of an infant invalidate wudu?

Tags: wudu

I wanted to know if accidentally touching urine invalidates wudu. Can someone throw some light on this for the following three situations:

1. The urine is that of a child that has still not been weaned, that is, an infant that is still on its mother's milk;
2. The urine of a child that has been weaned; and
3. The urine of an animal like a cat.

Jazakallahu khairan.

Comment: I have heard that for a boy, till he is only on mother's milk, his urine can be cleaned by wetting the cloth with water. After the boy start taking solid food, the urinated cloth need to be changed. For, baby girls, the cloth need to be changed even if they are on mother's milk. I don't have any reference for it. I hope it helps.

Comment: http://www.aussiemuslims.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-34659.html Read the answer here, by renowned ulema.

Answer (score 5):

Touching urine or any kind of Najas doesn't invalidate wudu. According to the Hanafi Madhab Wudu invalidiates only in these cases:

(1) Discharging urine or stool
(2) Discharge of gases;
(3) Flowing of blood or pus out of anything part of the body;
(4) Vomiting in mouthful;
(5) To sleep lying down or by resting the body against something;
(6) To faint due to some illness or by any other reason;
(7) Becoming insane or going mad.
(8) Laughing out loudly in Salah.

~Book of Hanafi Fuqh 'al Hidayah'.

Jazakumullah