# Is wudu valid if baby do urine on our clothes? Or we have to change our clothes and make wudu again?

Tags: wudu

Does it break wudu if kid/baby make your clothes dirty. and will it change our clothes everytime?

Comment: Relevant posts https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8597/does-touching-the-urine-of-an-infant-invalidate-wudu and https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33628/would-touching-the-private-parts-of-our-kids-also-invalid-our-wudu